# Puppet strange behaviour of execs

Tags: puppet

I use a function to install several libraries to my VM right now. However for some reason it always executes the chown exec even when the create exec is not used (because the library is already installed).

Is my understanding of subscribe wrong? I thought the second exec will only be executed when the one subscribed to is.

```rb
define add (
  $lib_version = undef,
  $lib_version_prefix = undef,
  $lib_name = undef,
  $user_path = "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
){
  file {"/var/www/lib/$lib_name":
    mode    => $php::folder_mode,
    owner   => $php::folder_owner,
    group   => $php::folder_group,
    ensure  => directory
  }
  exec {"create-$lib_name":
    cwd     => "/var/www/lib/$lib_name",
    command => "xxx",
    creates => "/var/www/lib/$lib_name/$lib_version",
  }
  exec {"chown-$lib_name":
    cwd => "/var/www/lib",
    command => "chown xxx",
    path => $user_path,
    subscribe => Exec["create-$lib_name"],
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No need to use an exec for the `chown` operation. Use the file resource instead.

```
 exec { "create-${lib_name}":
   cwd     => "/var/www/lib/${lib_name}",
   command => 'xxx',
   creates => "/var/www/lib/${lib_name}/${lib_version}"
 }

 file { "/var/www/lib/path/to/directory":
   ensure    => directory,
   owner     => 'root',
   group     => 'root',
   recurse   => true,
   subscribe => Exec["create-${lib_name}"
 }
```

Comment: I need to use it recursively though, will recurse => true work? And I still would need to know, how to write dependent execs like I tried to do. Thanks

Comment: recursion will work in the file resource. I have updated my answer to reflect his.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `file` type here is the better solution, but if you want an `exec` to only run when `subscribe`d or `notify`ing resources are changed, set `refreshonly => true` on your `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet does not execute statements in linear order (as is the code written) unless you define some constraints.

You need to enforce your ordering, this could be done with chaining arrows `~>` or `require` statements:

```java
  exec {"chown-$lib_name":
    cwd       => "/var/www/lib",
    command   => "chown xxx",
    path      => $user_path,
    require   => Exec["create-$lib_name"],
  }
```

`subscribe` means that the resource will be notified when dependent one changes. It is frequently used e.g. for restarting services, but not very useful in this case.